# Differences between angular 2, Angular 2 universal

Tags: angular

which are the differences between angular 2, Angular 2 universal?

i don't understand exactly the difference between angular 2 and angular 2 universal, which is the advantage to use angular 2 universal?

Comment: https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/ did you even read the tutorial?

Comment: The overview may also help to answer your question: https://universal.angular.io/overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Angular Universal is the library the awesome Angular team is working on to make building universal apps a smooth experience. The library fixes a lot of nightmare we had working with Angular 1. As a matter of fact, our worst nightmare in Angular 1 is what Angular Universal takes away in Angular 2.
And then, the advantages to use angular 2 universal are "better perceived performance", "optimized for search engine", and "site preview".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 is a frontend framework based on Javascript, whereas Angular 2 universal is a library used in angular 2 to prerender the js in angular 2 projects for better user experience and optimization for search-engines.

Hope this clarifies it at the high level, you can read further on the official documentation at https://universal.angular.io/